# Using Array functions Excel

Tags: excel

My sample data:
[image]

I am using this formula to get the total number of locations:

```
SUMPRODUCT(($I$9:$I$25=L9)*1)
```

I need to provide the QTY for the respective BINs, and I'm stuck!

How do I return the qty for the Part Number in each BIN?

Comment: I am looking for a single formula solution, not helper columns...

Comment: [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B). Or [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1). It's difficult to tell from your explanation.

Comment: Difficult to understand how you want the data returned, do you want in column N named B1 the count of total qty of said parts in bin B1?

Comment: for example, column N would contain only one value=> N9 would contain 99, the number of 44186's in BIN B1, the rest would contain zeros

Comment: That's what I thought, the formula bellow should give you want you wanted. Need to be a bit more specific on how you want the data returned next time.

Comment: OK thank you.  While your formula works, I need to now learn SUMIFS!! Next Time I will put prototype solution

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: you have in row 1 the bins labeled such as in N8 you have the bin "B1" if this is true then paste this formula in N9 and drag down and right to fill.

```
=SUMIFS($J:$J,$H:$H,N$8,$I:$I,$L9)
```